# How do I change the class of an element in blade based on the URL of the page?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0, and I would like to make the class of an element 'active' if the url contains the word 'dashboard'. I was able to achieve this in Laravel 5.4 as:

```
<li class="{{request()->is('dashboard') ? 'active':'inactive'}}">
```

But this does not work in Laravel 5.0. Can someone provide a solution which would work?

Comment: It should work in Laravel 5.0 as well since the is() method does exist. Scroll to the end of this doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests under section Determining If The Request Path Matches A Pattern.
Try `Request::is('dashboard')`

Comment: @Bhavyanshu okay so I attempted to use 'Request::is('dashboard')' instead, but now it is always giving it a class of inactive. My url is as: ..../dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really clean solution would be creating a helper function to help you like so:

```
function set_active($uri)
{
    return Request::is($uri) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
}
```

and then in your blade file:

```
<li class="{{set_active('dashboard')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@if (strpos(Request::url(), 'dashboard') !== false)
    <li class="active">
@else
    <li class="inactive">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the url CONTAINS dashboard you need to add some wild cards. right now you're just checking that the path IS dashboard. The example below will set class active any time the path starts with admin/hub

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('admin/hub*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
  <a href="{{ url('admin/hub') }}" id="hub">
   <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <span>Hub</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

If you want to set the class if the request contains dashboard ANYWHERE use

```
Request::is('*dashboard*') ? 'active' : ''
```